# how to change public IP address

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualmin

I'm having issue with my ubuntu + virtualmin.
I'm getting blocked from YouTube for getting information. And want to change my public IP address. I've tried with Dedicated IP in virtualmin and by modifying network interface `/etc/network/interfaces`.
Any solution to do this ?
PS: I'm using contabo server. And have 3 additional IPs.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the content of /etc/network/interfaces . Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit]. Also advise if your ISP provides the fixed IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit too minimal explained:

On my.contabo.com you can assign your IPs to the server and on Virtualmin additionally you assign the IP to your Virtual Server.

Probably all is fine until the next download overload attack ;-):

Webmin -> Networking -> Network Configuration you see your ethernet interface (eth0 or similar) and if your IPs are already activated then you have there all IPs listed as eth0:0, :1, :2.

If not you can activate the IP while you create a new Virtual Server.

Regards
Urs